# MS Access append query with a parameter fails with type conversion failure - text to text

Tags: ms-access, parameters, type-conversion, append

I am running an append query that selects records from an existing table in the database.  All the fields in the receiving table are defined as text.  Since this table will receive new records on a regular basis, I want to add a file date in text form to the record when it's written so I can identify when each record was added.  I don't need the file date to be an actual date, and it will not be the date I'm actually running the query. The field is defined as text, and the query prompts for the date.

Query from comment:

```sql
INSERT INTO tblMaster_Vendor ( Vendor_ID, FileDate ) 
SELECT DISTINCT FULL_EXTRACT.Vendor_ID, [File Date] AS Expr1 
FROM FULL_EXTRACT 
WHERE FULL_EXTRACT.Vendor_Type = "84"
```

Every time, I get a 'data type conversion error', even though I'm adding text (like 20171106) to a text field.

Here's what I've tried:
- changed the field name and prompt from 'File Date' to 'Entered' in case there was a reserved word issue
- Entered straight text into the parameter query box (aaaabbcc)
- Changed the table field type to date/time and entered the date as 11/10/2017
- Entered the text in the parameter box with quotes ('aaaabbcc')

If I don't try to enter the file date as part of the append query, I can run an update query after the append and update the field to my desired value (20171106).

Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Comment: Perhaps you could share your sql with us.

Comment: Sure.  It's pretty basic:

Comment: INSERT INTO tblMaster_Vendor ( Vendor_ID, FileDate )
SELECT DISTINCT FULL_EXTRACT.Vendor_ID, [File Date] AS Expr1
FROM FULL_EXTRACT
WHERE FULL_EXTRACT.Vendor_Type = "84"  where Full_Extract is a file I received weekly containing all our vendors.  I want to append just the vendors with type 84 to my tblMaster_Vendor, and add the file date so I can keep track of when the record was received.

Comment: Based on the sql you provided: If your Vendor_Type is a numeric field, then you should remove the quotes: `... WHERE FULL_EXTRACT.Vendor_Type = 84`

Comment: Vendor_ID is a text field, and it's working fine.  The problem is the field [File Date], which is also text.  The query prompts for the value to append to this field,  and whether I enter 20171106 or '20171106' I get the type conversion error.

Comment: Try explicitly declaring `File Date` as [query parameter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-parameters-to-ask-for-input-when-running-a-query-c2806d3d-d500-45a8-8507-ec6af351b6ed) with data type Text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Cstr function? e.g., something of this structure?

```
INSERT INTO Table2 ( ID, fileupdated ) SELECT Table1.ID, CStr(Now()) AS Expr1 FROM Table1 WHERE (((Table1.ID)>2));
```